Demonstrating $SU=U(\sigma^2 I+D^2)$ as a Sufficient Condition in Maximum Likelihood Estimation
I am working on an exercise related to maximum likelihood estimation (in the context of principal component analysis) for the distribution
$$p(x) = Gauss(b, WW^T+\sigma^2I)$$
In particular, I want to find an estimator for the matrix $W$, where the log-likelihood function for a set of observations $\{x_i\}$ is given by:
$$
\log L(\{x_i\} \mid b,W,\sigma^2) = -\frac{n}{2} \left(d\log(2\pi) + \log |C| + \operatorname{Tr}(C^{-1}S)\right)
$$
where $S$ is the sample covariance matrix and $C$ is assumed to be a non-singular covariance matrix.
I am asked to show that a sufficient condition is $SU=U(\sigma^2 I+D^2)$, under the assumption that $W \neq 0$ and $S \neq C$ and where $U D V^T$ is the singular value decomposition of $W$, with $U \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ and $D, V \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ and $D$ diagonal.
If I take the derivative of the log-likelihood function with respect to $W$, after some calculations, I get:
$$
\frac{\partial \log L}{\partial W} = n(C^{-1}S C^{-1}W - C^{-1}W)
$$
and by setting to zero I find $S C^{-1}W = W$. Now I should show that this is implied by the previous condition ($SU=U(\sigma^2 I+D^2)$), but I am stuck. Could someone help me show this sufficiency?
